# Create a function for add_new_field in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a function for a task I mentioned earlier for adding a new field to some files that are stored in one folder. I read about the function method in Python and followed but it does not work. I would be happy if someone could guide me about it.

```
def newfield(infile,outfile):
    infile.readlines()
    outfile = ["%s\t%s" %(item.strip(),2) for item in infile]
    outfile.write("\n".join(output))
    outfile.close()
    return outfile
```

and then I try to call it:

```
a = open("E:/SAGA/data/2006last/test/325145404.all","r")
b = open("E:/SAGA/data/2006last/test/325145404_edit.all","w")
newfield(a,b)
```

Moreover, when we create a function, should we call it in a same python shell or we can same it as a file and then call it?

Comment: **What** doesn't work? What output did you expect to get, and what output did you find instead? What does your *input* look like?

Comment: it gives this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    newfield(a,b);
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 4, in newfield
    outfile.write("\n".join(output))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is you're assigning the list you build to the same name as the `output` file. You're also reading all of the lines out of the file and not assigning the result anywhere, so when your list comprehension iterates over it, it's already at the end of the file. So you can drop the `readlines` line.

```
def newfield(infile,outfile):
    output = ["%s\t%s" %(item.strip(),2) for item in infile]
    outfile.write("\n".join(output))
    outfile.close()
    return outfile
```

Comment: I tried ur suggestion. when I call this function as :    a = open("E:/SAGA/data/2006last/test/325155405.all","r")
b = open("E:/SAGA/data/2006last/test/325155405_edit.all","w")
 newfield(a,b);    it does nt create a new outfile

Comment: Is there an error? Also did you start a new python prompt after updating the code?

Comment: yes the error is :     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    newfield(a,b);
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 3, in newfield
    outfile.write("\n".join(output))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: maybe my problem is the way to call it. I wrote the function in python GUI and called afterwards in the same page,is it correct?

Comment: That error looks to be from the orignal code you posted, rather than the code above

Comment: Yes, that's because in your original code you made a list called `outfile`, and lists don't have a `write` attribute. In the code I posted I renamed the list to `output` which is what I think you intended, so on the `write` line the `outfile` variable still points to the file object

Comment: If it's not working still, post a full runnable example in an edit to the question

Comment: Thank you very much it works now properly :). I have another question in this regard. I wld like to save this function and maybe sometimes later, I call it again. should I save it as a *.py file? bcos now I have the function and the calling commands in one Python Shell.

Comment: Yes absolutely, you can save it in a py file, then when you want to use it you can [`import`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) it

Comment: that is great. wld u plz give an example how it is possible to import it?

Comment: Did you check the link to the modules tutorial in my last comment? That has examples of what you're asking

Comment: unfortunately I did not. If it is not too much to ask, wld u plz repeat it here.

Answer (score 0):

The line `infile.readlines()` consumes the whole input file. All lines are read and forgotten because they are not assigned to a variable.

The construct `["%s\t%s" %(item.strip(),2) for item in infile]` is a list comprehension. This expression returns a list. By assigning it to the variable outfile the old value of outfile - probably a file object - is forgotten and replaced by the list returned by the list comprehension. This list object does not have a write method. By assigning the list to another variable the file object in outfile is preserved.

Try this:

```
def newfield(infile,outfile):
    items = ["%s\t%s" %(item.strip(),2) for item in infile]
    outfile.write("\n".join(items))
    outfile.close()
    return outfile
```

Comment: I tried ur suggestion. when I call this function as : a = open("E:/SAGA/data/2006last/test/325155405.all","r") b = open("E:/SAGA/data/2006last/test/325155405_edit.all","w") newfield(a,b);  it gives this error :<closed file 'E:/SAGA/data/2006last/test/325145404_ed.all', mode 'w' at 0x02CE8650>

Comment: sorry would u plz explain more what do u exactly mean?I do not get u.

Comment: thank you for ur help. I tried the new code u recommended. when I call ,I receive this error:  <closed file 'E:/SAGA/data/2006last/test/325145404_ed_2.all', mode 'w' at 0x02CE86A8>  what do u think it refers to?

Comment: Do you use the returned file after calling the function?

Comment: what does this error means?    File "<pyshell#81>", line 3, in newfield1
    outfile.write("\n".join(items))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: @Andreas Schlapsi:what do u exactly mean by(Do you use the returned file after calling the function? ) ? u mean I should say return at the end of calling?